# Calling a function in Aspx.cs with change in dropdownbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a page where in a change in the value from the drop down box will pass the corresponding text in the drop down box to get the values from the database.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropid" runat="server" OnChange="Getvaluesfromaspx"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I want the function named "Getvaluesfromaspx" in the aspx.cs to be called from the aspx file.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event instead of "OnChange" event.

Also set AutoPostBack property value to true.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropid" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Getvaluesfromaspx"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And in code behind

```
protected void Getvaluesfromaspx(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    //Do whatever want to do here. 
}
```